# R function to get R squared and p value for the regression

Tags: r, regression, p-value

First off, I'll start by saying that I do not know how to use R, but I need to do reduced major axis regression for the two variables below, and the lmodel2 function can do this. I learnt the code below to obtain the intercept and slope for the regression equation. However I don't get a R squared or a p-value for the regression. How would I do this? The code I have used so far is below.

```
Tensor_force=c(1.72,1.48,1.37,0.81,0.75,0.96,0.96,0.78,0.54,0.67,0.75,0.66,0.4)
Stapedius_force=c(0.8,0.58,1.07,0.82,0.77,0.98,0.99,0.98,0.92,1.06,1.19,1.32,1.18)

library(lmodel2)

lmodel2(Stapedius_force ~ Tensor_force,,"relative", "relative",0)
```

Answer (score 4):

```r
library(lmodel2)
mod1 <- lmodel2(Stapedius_force ~ Tensor_force,,"relative", "relative",0)
#> No permutation test will be performed
```

The `lmodel2` object created by the `lmodel2()` function is basically a list,
that is printed in a fashion so that the user can better read the results.
You can access individual values by subsetting that list. If you write
`mod1$` and look at the auto complete options you’ll see the available values names.
`rsquare` and `P.param` are the names you are looking for:

```r
mod1$rsquare
#> [1] 0.2905577
mod1$P.param # 2 tailed
#> [1] 0.0573178
mod1$P.param/2 # 1 tailed
#> [1] 0.0286589
```

If you are working with several different iterations of the same model
the `broom` package and its `glance()` function are very useful, as it
extracts the model quality measurments as a `data.frame`/`tibble` so you can
easily conduct further analysis on these values. See https://broom.tidymodels.org/ to learn more.

```r
library(broom)
glance(mod1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   r.squared theta p.value      H  nobs
#>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1     0.291  28.2  0.0573 0.0986    13
```